# Al hacer print me aparece una 'u' delante de los nombres

Tags: python, lista

No entiendo porque al hacer un `print` de una lista aparecen una 'u'  delante de los nombres.

```
def BuscarDef():
    
    Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Productos")
    ListaProductos=Cursor.fetchall()
    for AAA in ListaProductos:
        print ('Nombre: ',AAA[0],'Numero: ',AAA[1])
    Conexion.close()

BuscarDef()
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
('Nombre: ', u'Juan', 'Numero: ', u'123123123')
('Nombre: ', u'Paco', 'Numero: ', u'678587123')
```

Comment: El `u` es por Unicode, pero es raro el comportamiento que se muestren así desde en print, ¿Python2x?

Comment: No, es python3. ¿Influye en algo?

Comment: Es raro, el resultado que obtienes me parecía más consistente con la 2x. Si hay diferencias, en la 2x se distinguen entre unicode y no unicode, en python 3x toda cadena es unicode.

Comment: ¿La base de datos cual es? ¿sqlite? ¿mysql?

Comment: sqlite o sqlite3 creo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

son strings unicode (utf8). Si quieres que las imprima como strings ASCII puedes castearlas con

```
str(cadena_utf8)
```

En tu caso

```
print('Nombre: %s  Numero: %s' % (str(AAA[0]), str(AAA[1]) ))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,
pero me podría aclarar una cosa, ¿Por qué si yo hago algo simplre como `N5=['HH','AA','SS'] print(N5)` Me suelta la lista **sin** las 'u' delante, y en cambio en la pregunta principal me pone las u delante?

Comment: me imagino que tu origen de datos viene en utf8

Comment: Entiendo, ¿y hay algún modo de cambiarlo desde el principio de un código para no tener que poner `print('Nombre: %s  Numero: %s'` siempre que quiera hacer un print?

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente lo que te está informando es que la cadena se trata de una cadena Unicode, es decir una cadena multi-byte. Primero que nada, lo que estás mostrando:

```
('Nombre: ', u'Juan', 'Numero: ', u'123123123')
('Nombre: ', u'Paco', 'Numero: ', u'678587123')
```

no parece ser el `print` de tu código sino el `print` de la lista completa de filas que retorna `fetchall()`, esta distinción es importante, por lo siguiente, una cadena `unicode` puede definirse explícitamente con el literal `u`:

```
x = u'Cadena'
print(x)
Cadena
```

Por más que la cadena se especifique con `u` la impresión por pantalla no arrastra dicho literal, ni siquiera se muestran las comillas, se muestra el dato puro. Distinto es cuando usamos el método `repr()`

```
x = u'Cadena'
print(repr(x))
u'Cadena'
```

Esto es justamente lo que pasa cuando imprimimos una lista, las cadenas que contienen se representan con `repr()`

```
x = u'Cadena'
lista = [x]

print(lista)
[u'Cadena')

print(lista[0])
Cadena
```

Cuando imprimimos la lista, aparecen las `u`, cuando accedemos al dato individual (la cadena) ya no. Es importante entender esto, una cosa es el dato (la cadena) y otra la representación del mismo (la lista que contiene la cadena).

Convertir las cadenas leídas de `unicode` a `ascii` o `latin1`, puede resolver también esta situación, pero hay conversiones que no son reversibles, por lo cual debiera ser tu última alternativa, o al menos la alternativa más pensada.  Puedes modificar el tratamiento por defecto de las cadenas directamente desde la conexión de `sqlite` ni bien la abres, usando [`text_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory), por ejemplo:

```
Conexion.text_factory = str
```

O bien puedes interpretar las cadenas con una codificación en particular:

```
Conexion.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, 'latin1')
```

Nota: Este comportamiento que muestras me sigue pareciendo más consistente con la versión 2x de Python.